# Using epsilon -delta definition to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} (x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}) = 8+ \sqrt[3]{2} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I'm trying to use the  $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 2} (x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}) = 8+ \sqrt[3]{2} $. I already know how to prove continuity for cubic root using $\epsilon$-$\delta$, but now that it's mixed up with cubed $x$, I'm confused. What I've done so far is this:

I need to show that
$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists \delta >0$ s.t. if $0<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|x^3+\sqrt[3]{x}-8-\sqrt[3]{2}|<\varepsilon$.

I've organized the $|x^3 +\sqrt[3]{x}-8-\sqrt[3]{2} |$ to $|x-2|\left|\frac{(x^2+2x+4)( x^{2/3}+(2x)^{1/3}+2^{2/3})+1 }{x^{2/3}+(2x)^{1/3}+2^{2/3}}\right|$.

Now I think I need to make sure that $x^{2/3}+(2x)^{1/3}+2^{2/3}$ doesn't get too small, but I have no idea how. How should I set $\delta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality:
$$|x^3-8+\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]2|\leq|x^3-8|+|\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]2|$$
If you know that $\lim\limits_{x\to2}x^3=8$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to2}\sqrt[3]x=\sqrt[3]2$, you can find $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $|x^3-8|<\frac\varepsilon2$ if $|x-2|<\delta_1$ and $|\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]2|<\frac\varepsilon2$ if $|x-2|<\delta_2$.

Just set $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Mean Value Theorem, for $x,y \geq 1$, $|x^{1/3}- y^{1/3}| \leq \frac{1}{3}|x-y|.$

Let $f(x):= x^3 + x^{1/3}$. Then for $x,y \in [1,3]$ we have

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x-y||x^2 +xy +y^2| + \frac{1}{3}|x-y| \leq 27|x-y| + \frac{1}{3} |x-y| \leq 28|x-y|.$$

In particular, $\forall x \in [1,3]$

$$|f(2) - f(x)| \leq 28|2-x|.$$

So given $\epsilon > 0$, pick $\delta < \frac{1}{28}$ to conclude.